# How to create tutorial when the first time open an app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Some apps got tutorial when the first time open.It seems cool.

I'm trying to create an opening tutorial that consists of four panes for my AngularJs app.

I build my app with css3 and html5 ,use cordova to generate apk.

How to create tutorial for my app when the first time open it?

Is there any solution?

Thanks a lot!

Sorry maybe I didn't make myself clear.The app is almost done,and splash screen has done.

But I need few pages or images on the first time run.

Answer (score 3):

Use database. For example if you use localStorage, inside the deviceready function

```
check=localStorage.getItem('first_time');
if(check.length<0)
{
    startTutorial();
    localStorage.setItem('first_time','NO it is old');
}
```

After the first run value will be changed and tutorial will be shown once.

You can use other databases like indexedDB or webSQL.

Comment: Thank u.I didn't get enough reputations to vote up.I will try on it.